# ¿Como dar valor a input con una variable global jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql

Tengo un select que en un archivo js me esta siriviendo para distintas cosas como un change para que me liste aquellas ciudades que dependen del id del pais, resulta que ahora necesito es que cuando se haga click en el option `(en el select del pais)`, ejemplo en el pais MEXICO me tome ese id y me lo guarde en una variable global...

para luego a un input que esta dentro de un formulario darle ese valor y guardarlo junto con las ciudad que se ingrese, es decir que al obtener ese valor  se pueda guardar algo como lo siguiente:

```
name:"id_pais"
value: "5"

name:"nombre_ciudad"
value : "monterrey"
```

Espero haberme hecho entender y agradeceria su colaboracion.

**ESTE ES EL CODIGO QUE ESTOY USANDO HASTA AHORA**

```
    var IdPais;
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {   
        function getPais()
        {
            return $.ajax({ url: 'configuracion/lista_pais',    type: 'GET', dataType: 'json'});
        }

        getPais()
        .done(function(respuesta)
        {
            try
            {
                var resultado = respuesta;
                for(var i = resultado.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                  // AQUI HAGO EL OPTION PARA LISTAR LOS PAISES
                }
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                console.info(e);
            }
        });

        // ACÁ HAGO EL CHANGE PARA LISTAR EN UNA TABLA LAS CIUDADES
        $('#paises').change(function(event)
        {
            event.preventDefault();

            //aqui supuestamente declaro la variable global 
           IdPais = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({url: 'configuracion/listar_ciudades', type: 'POST', dataType: 'json', data: {'id_pais': IdPais},})  
            .done(function(respuesta)
            {
                try
                {
                    var resultado = respuesta;
                    for(var i = resultado.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        var rowNode = ciudades
                        .row.add([
                                    resultado[i].ciudad_id,
                                    resultado[i].ciudad_nombren,
                                    '<center><button id="editar"  class="btn btn-info" style="background: orange; border-color: orange; width: 30px;  height: 30px;  text-align: center;  padding: 6px 0;  font-size: 12px;  line-height: 1.428571429;  border-radius: 15px;" title="editar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"</span></button></center>',    
                                ])
                            .draw()
                        .node();
                    }
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                    console.info(e);
                }
            })
            .fail(function(){
                console.log("error");
            });
        });

$('#id_pais').val(IdPais); // Es aqui donde se deberia de guardar el id del pais
```

**HTML**

```
    <form>
     <input type="hidden" name="id_pais" id="id_pais">
    <input type="text" name="nombre_ciudad" id="nombre_ciudad">
    <input type="submit" value="guardar">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sencillamente agregarias esta linea de codigo para que asigne el valor del SELECT a la CAJA HIDDEN:

primero has un `alert($this.val());` para ver si te muestra el valor del select

luego lo pasamos asi:

//aqui supuestamente declaro la variable global

```
   IdPais = $(this).val();
```

//En nvez de una variable global se lo asignamos a la caja de texto cada vez que cambie

```
   var valor=$this.val();
   $("#id_pais").val(valor);
```

SUPONIENDO QUE: todo esta en el mismo formulario, sorry por la respuesta tan mal estructurada no tengo mouse y hacerlo a puro teclado es dificil
No es necesario hacerla global, pues si la obtienes la pasas directamente a tu caja de texto y wuala milagros de JQuery

Te deho este ejemplo:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select[name=numeros]").change(function(){
            alert($('select[name=numeros]').val());
            $('input[name=valor]').val($(this).val());
        });
});
</script>

<html>
<select name="numeros">
<option value=1>UNO</option>
<option value=2>DOS</option>
<option value=3>TRES</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="valor">Valor

</html>
```

Comment: Hola @Victor A. gracias por tu interes, por lo que entiendo entonces no creo una variable global? tu ejemplo lo haria dentro del CHANGE?...Saludos.

Comment: no, no crees la global pues es innecesaria, mas facil es aprovechar la bondad de jquery de que cada vez que cambie tu select te pase el valor que tiene a una caja de texto, trata de hacer el alert que te menciono, pues a veces para obtener el valor del select no se usa simplemente this

Comment: Ok @Victor A. Excelente muchas gracias.